# For for foldables

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, foldable

`for` is `flip traverse`.

`forM` is `flip mapM`.

And so on with `for_`, etc.

What about `foldMap`? It's lonely.

`flip foldMap = ?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be silly if every 2-argument function had a flipped counterpart. The reason the `for` variants are worthwhile is mainly that they play so nicely together with `do` notation, in a way that closely remembers e.g. Python loops.

```
main = do
  ...
  forM_ [0..9] $ \i -> do
     print i
     ...
  return ()
```

For `foldMap` you could still benefit from a syntax-heralding `$`+lambda on the RHS, however you wouldn't be in a monad (at least not one used as such), wouldn't use `do` notation, and probably would need some parentheses anyway. So there's not much advantage to be had over the regular `foldMap` with a parenthesized function in the middle.

Comment: Thanks, so what about `for` itself? No monad there...is is possible to exploit applicative structure, though one can't use the `do` notation?

Comment: One *can* use `do` notation, if you enable `ApplicativeDo`. But it's useful to think of `for` as something "intended" for monadic computations, even if it's been generalized to `Applicative`s instead. (Just like `traverse` itself is basically a replacement for `mapM`, even though it works with more than just monads.)

Comment: FWIW, I agree that it would be silly for *all* two-argument functions to have a flipped counterpart. But for iterations over collections in particular I find the standard library to be overwhelmingly wrongly-ordered. I almost always have a short name for the collection already, and a complicated expression for the thing I'm doing with each element. I kinda wish we had *only* the flipped counterpart for a lot of them -- so not two variants, but not the variant we got, either.